# Gravity Forms - make selection based on conditional logic

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I feel like this should be easy but I may be missing something, I have an administrative field on a Gravity Form that needs to be populated as Yes or No based on conditional logic. I was able to get it to do one or the other by only "showing" it and giving a default value but I really need it to be populated both ways with Yes or No. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We covered a technique for achieving this here:

https://gravitywiz.com/how-to-check-checkboxes-and-other-choice-based-fields-conditionally/

TLDR;

1. Create a separate form to store your logic via entries.
2. Use Populate Anything to populate (and select) the proper choice(s) based on the selections made in the current form.

Comment: Thanks Dave - I did not want to create an additional form since we will be creating numerous copies of the form with different role access. I found a solution by using this function: https://gist.github.com/senlin/af45010ccfb44ee6c707 I created the 2 separate answers with conditional logic and then an additional field that merged the data from each since only one would be populated.

Comment: Glad you found another one of our solutions.  One possible downside to that approach is that you'll have 2 extra fields on every form. With my suggested approach, you would only have one extra form that could then be used to populate selected choices on all the other forms with no extra fields required.